# Chaining of Relational operators is giving wrong output

Tags: c, operators, comparison-operators

Can anyone explain this to me? Did I do something wrong? 
When I run the program it doesn't show me the right answer.

ex : when I type weight = 50 kg and height = 130 cm the answer should be

> "Your BMI is 29.58. You are overweight2.You will have a chance to cause high blood pressure and diabetes need to control diet. And fitness."

but the answer that shows is

> "Your BMI is 29.58. You are normal......"

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main() {
  float weight, height, bmi;

  printf("\nWelcome to program");

  printf("\nPlease enter your weight(kg) :");
  scanf("%f", &weight);

  printf("\nPlease enter your height(cm) :");
  scanf("%f", &height);

  bmi=weight/((height/100)*(height/100));

  if(bmi<18.50) { 
    printf("Your bmi is : %.2f",bmi);
    printf("You are Underweight.You should eat quality food and a sufficient amount of energy and exercise proper.");
  } else if(18.5<=bmi<23) {
    printf("Your bmi is : %.2f \nYou are normal.You should eat quality food and exercise proper.",bmi);
  } else if(23<=bmi<25) {
    printf("Your bmi is : %.2f \nYou are overweight1 if you have diabetes or high cholesterol,You should lose weight body mass index less than 23. ",bmi);
  } else if(25<=bmi<30) {
    printf("Your bmi is : %.2f \nYou are overweight2.You will have a chance to cause high blood pressure and diabetes need to control diet. And fitness.",bmi);
  } else if(bmi>=30) {
    printf("Your bmi is : %.2f \nYou are Obesity.Your risk of diseases that accompany obesity.you run the risk of highly pathogenic. You have to control food And serious fitness.",bmi);
  } else {
    printf(" Please try again! ");
  }

  return 0;
  getch();
}
```

Comment: I don't know C that well, but does it support `x < y < z` comparisons...!? Usually that's `x < y && y < z`...

Comment: @deceze Nopes, you're right. it _translates_ to _something else_. :)

Comment: `18.5 <= bmi < 23` will result in `(18.5 <= bmi) < 23`, so `(18.5 <= 29.58) < 23` => `false < 23` => `0 < 23` => `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, what you've tried

```
 else if(18.5<=bmi<23)
```

No, this kind of **chaining** of Relational operators is not possible in C. You should write

```
 else if((18.5<=bmi) &&  (bmi < 23))
```

to check `bmi` value in `[18.5, 23)` and so on for the other cases.

---

EDIT:

Just to elaborate about the *issue*, an expression like

```
18.5<=bmi<23
```

is perfectly valid C syntax. However, it is essentially the same as

```
((18.5<=bmi) < 23 )
```

due to the [operator associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

So, first the `(18.5<=bmi)` is evaluated and the result , (0 or 1) gets to get comapred against `23`, which is certainly not you want here.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
18.5<=bmi<23
```

means the same as

```
(18.5 <= bmi) < 23
```

In other words the value of `bmi` is never compared to `23`. You must not use that kind of math-syntax in C, it should be written as:

```
(18.5 <= bmi) && (bmi < 23)
```

So it's really *two* comparisons of the variable, and must be written using the boolean-and (`&&`)  operator to make this explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C language **does** show you the right answer of what you've tried.

There is no syntax like this in C for comparison (but yes, it's a valid syntax):

```
else if(18.5<=bmi<23)
```

it should be this:

```
else if((18.5<=bmi)&&(bmi < 23))
```